# Best way to merge video and audio?

Tags: android, audio, video, ffmpeg, muxer

I want to merge `video(.mp4)` and `audio(.wav, .pcm)`,
video and audio has same lengh.

What is the best way (fastest merging time)?
muxer? ffmpeg?

Comment: Did you find the answer?